# Renaming a number of columns using for loop (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe below has a number of columns but columns names are random numbers.

daily1=

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   ... 640 777 674 842 786 865 809 674 679 852
    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 108 29  74  102 82  62  83  68  30  61
2 rows × 244 columns
```

I would like to organise columns names in numerical order(from 0 to 243)

I tried

```
for i, n in zip(daily1.columns, range(244)):
    asd=daily1.rename(columns={i:n})
    asd
```

but output has not shown...

Ideal output is

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   ... 640 777 674 842 786 865 809 674 679 852
    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 108 29  74  102 82  62  83  68  30  61
```

Could I get some advice guys? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reorder the columns you can try that

```py
columns = sorted(list(df.columns), reverse=False)
df = df[columns]
```

If you just want to rename the columns then you can try

```py
df.columns = [i for i in range(df.shape[1])]
```